# Term Description Echo or Return - display problems

Tags: shortcode, tags

I've got a useful snippet of code to create a shortcode and display post tags and their descriptions on posts. I'm trying to display all tags assigned to the particular live post, not all tags for the site etc.

if i use `echo` the term/description end up displaying at the top of the content rather than within the element where the shortcode is; and if I use `return` only the first tag is displayed and other tags are ignored.

A solution would be greatly appreciated. thanks

```
function returnpost_tags() {
     return get_the_tag_list( '', ', ', '' );
}
add_shortcode( 'post-tags', 'returnpost_tags' );

function returnpost_tagsdesc() {
    // get tags by post ID 
    $post_ID = get_the_ID();

    // here, you can add any custom tag
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_ID , 'post_tag', array( "description" => "ids" ) );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        $term_ID = $term->term_id;

        // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                continue;
        }

        //echo '' . $term->name . '';
        return term_description($term_ID);

        // another option
        // echo  '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'post-tags-desc', 'returnpost_tagsdesc' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store every tags in a variable, and then return the whole thing. Define an empty value before the `foreach` and append the data to it. Don't use the `return` inside the loop, since it will quit the loop once it reaches the first `return`. Take a look at this piece of your code that I have modified:

```
// Define an empty variable
$data = '';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    $term_ID = $term->term_id;

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            continue;
    }

    // Append each term's description to it
    $data .= term_description($term_ID);

}
// Return the entire data
return $data;
```